# SQL Puzzle: How to generate row numbers ? (a classic puzzle with a cruel twist)

Tags: sql, puzzle, row-number

* A more refine version of this challenge can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957837/sql-challenge-how-to-generate-row-numbers-ordered-by-non-unique-values).

---

## The Puzzle

We got a table t:

```
create table t (i int not null);
```

The goal is to write, **under the requirements specified below**, a query that returns the same results as -

```
select t.i,row_number() over (order by t.i) as rn from t;
```

It might help you to know that there is another table in the database -

```
create table s (i int   not null    unique);
```

All I can tell you about table **s**, except for its definition, is that it has the same number of rows as table **t**, or maybe more.

## Requirements

- The solution should be a single SQL query (sub-queries are fine).
- The use of any table other than **t** (and perhaps **s**), including table functions, **is not allowed**.
- Only the following clauses are allowed: **SELECT**, **FROM**, **WHERE**, **GROUP BY**, **HAVING**, **ORDER BY** and **WITH** (**but not recursive!!**).
- The use of analytic functions **is not allowed**.
- The use of **rownum**, **rowid**, **guid** and their like **is not allowed**.
- The use of T-SQL, PL/SQL etc. **is not allowed**.
- The use of UDF (User Defined Functions) **is not allowed**.
- The use of variables **is not allowed**.

## Data Sample

```
create table t (i int not null);

insert into t (i) values (1);
insert into t (i) values (2);
insert into t (i) values (3);
insert into t (i) values (3);
insert into t (i) values (4);
insert into t (i) values (5);
insert into t (i) values (5);
insert into t (i) values (5);
insert into t (i) values (6);
insert into t (i) values (7);

create table s (i int not null unique);

insert into s (i) values (3);
insert into s (i) values (12);
insert into s (i) values (13);
insert into s (i) values (28);
insert into s (i) values (41);
insert into s (i) values (52);
insert into s (i) values (56);
insert into s (i) values (57);
insert into s (i) values (83);
insert into s (i) values (91);
insert into s (i) values (97);
insert into s (i) values (99);
```

## Requested result

```
         I         RN
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          3
         3          4
         4          5
         5          6
         5          7
         5          8
         6          9
         7         10
```

Comment: There is a whole SE site for puzzles. But this is not the place.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) I just searched stackoverflow for "puzzle" and got 29,743 results.

Comment: @sstan - I'm pretty confident that the OP has a solution. Showing it would somewhat detract from the puzzle.

Comment: @juergend, this is not the case.

Comment: The same difference of opinion exists in Math SE. I am on the side of posting puzzles, interesting questions etc. I don't mind if people are looking for free labor; I am free to refuse to give it. I see the site as a learning place; a quiz, puzzle, hw problem etc. should be judged on its quality, not on whether it is hw coming from a lazy student, or an attempt at getting free consultation. One can learn a lot from solving (or reading others' solutions) to such problems, no matter the OP's intent or motives.

Comment: _The use of T-SQL, PL/SQL etc. is not allowed._ This makes it pretty difficult.

Answer (score 3):

The following will work almost all the time:

```
with tt as (
      select t.i, t.i + rand() as new_i
      from t
     )
select tt.i,
       (select count(*)
        from tt tt2
        where tt2.new_i <= tt.new_i
       ) as rn
from tt;
```

Note:  The function for `rand()` exists in all databases that support `with`, although the exact function (or combination) varies by database.

EDIT:

It is much more complicated to get something that works all the time.  But:

```
with n as (
      select (select count(*) from s s2 where s2.i <= s.i) as n
      from s
     ),
     tt as (
      select i, count(*) as num
      from t
      group by i
     ),
     ttt as 
      (select tt.*,
             (select sum(num) from tt tt2 where tt2.i < tt.i
             ) as cume_num
      from tt
     )
select ttt.i, coalesce(cume_num, 0) + n.n
from ttt join
     n
     on n.n <= ttt.num;
```

I sort of like the first way better ;)

Comment: Yes it would, by "all the time" would be much better :-)

Comment: @KamilG., the first solution has a good probability to work on this small dataset , but it is not guaranteed,

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I'm aware of limitations that this solution introduces ;-)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I liked the idea with the cume_num

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this:

```
with 
    grp as 
        (select   i, 
                  count(*) cnt,
                  (select count(*) from t where i < t1.i) cntBefore
         from     t t1
         group by i),
    r as 
        (select   (select count(*) from s where i <= s1.i) rn
         from     s s1)
select     grp.i, r.rn
from       r
inner join grp on r.rn between grp.cntBefore + 1 and grp.cntBefore + grp.cnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with 
    num_gen as (
      select   (select count(*) from s where i <= s1.i) n
      from     s s1
    ),
    groups as (
      select   i, count(*) as ct
      from     t
      group by i
    )
select g.i, ng.n + (select count(*) from t where t.i < g.i) rn
from   num_gen ng inner join groups g on ng.n <= g.ct;
```

**Note**: Initially I offered a different solution, shown below for historical perspective (the first two comments refer to it). The OP is right, of course; I butchered a good idea. In the solution above I restored the idea to its proper simplicity.

```
    -- OLD solution (replaced by the one above)
with 
    num_gen as (
      select   (select count(*) from s where i <= s1.i) n
      from     s s1
    ),
    groups as (
      select   i, count(*) as ct
      from     t
      group by i
    ),
    new_numbers as (
      select g.i i, g.i + power(10, -ng.n) new_i
      from   num_gen ng inner join groups g on ng.n <= g.ct
    )
select   nn.i, (select count(*) from new_numbers where new_i <= nn.new_i) rn
from     new_numbers nn;
```

Comment: It's O.K. but the use of POWER is dangerous here. You can get into overflow issues pretty fast.

Comment: lol - right; at least I should use powers of 2. But when we solve logical problems we aren't supposed to think about the physical layer, right?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - I did butcher a good idea though; it was past midnight... I fixed it now, I think it works quite a bit better. Which, if I am reading trincot's solution correctly, is now almost the same as his.

Answer (score 1):

My variation:

```
with        seq_num (i)
            as
            (
                select      (select count (*) as i from s s2 where s2.i <= s1.i)

                from        s s1
            )           

           ,t_with_seq (i,i_seq)
            as
            (
                select      t.i     as i
                           ,s.i     as i_seq

                from                   (select      i
                                                   ,count (*)   as occurrences

                                        from        t

                                        group by    i
                                        )
                                        t

                            join        seq_num s

                            on          s.i <= t.occurrences
            )

select      ts1.i
           ,(select count (*) from t_with_seq ts2 where ts2.i  < ts1.i or (ts2.i  = ts1.i and ts2.i_seq  <= ts1.i_seq))    as rn

from        t_with_seq ts1

order by    rn
;
```